# Printing a line in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, printing, matlab-guide

I am trying to a matlab GUI application and I want to display a number of lines(15 or so). Each line is calculated after each iteration inside a loop. If I use `set(handles.outText,'string',num);` after each itration, the previous text is replaced instead of appending to it. Also, I need each line to be on a separate line instead of everything cluttered together. Please help me out!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to show your code. How do you populate num ?
I guess you are replacing it each time, you have to append the string to the num variable. In order to write multiple lines, you should use a cell array for your program.

```
A = {'1st line', '2nd line'};
set(handles.outText, 'String', A);
```